# declare-fun vs declare-const in SMT2

Tags: z3

I get confused about the following two declarations. For me, they describe the same thing: an integer variable `x`.

- `(declare-const x Int)`
- `(declare-fun x () Int)`

Is there any context that make them different in performance or provide different model?
Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, `(declare-const x Int)` is just syntax sugar `(declare-fun x () Int)`.  There is no difference in performance. Note that `declare-const` is not part of the SMT-Lib 2.0 standard.

Comment: Thanks. So I guess the Z3 tutorial is old, since it illustrates with many declare-const.